# Fluent API, EF 4.1: a problem of inheritance and foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-first, ef4-code-only

There are several simple classes:

The first class:

```
public class User
{
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public string Username { get; set; }

   // ...

   public ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
}
```

The second class:

```
public class Publication 
{
   public int PublicationId { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }

   / ...

   public User Author { get; set; }
}
```

The third class:

```
public class Topic: Publication 
{
   public string TopicContent { get; set; }

   // ...
}
```

After creating a database for my model I have the following stucture of the database:

**Users**

UserId

UserName

**Publications**

PublicationId

Title

TopicContent

Author_UserId

User_UserId

As you can see I get two fields Author_UserId and User_UserId having identical role in the table Publications.

How can I merge this fields into one field using Fluent API or Data Annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible to have the same foreign key column in the `Publications` table. `Publication.Author` and `User.Topics` cannot be the endpoints of one and the same association. You could have a `Publication` instance which isn't a `Topic` and a reference to a `User`:

```
User user = new User() { Topics = new List<Topic>() };
Publication publication = new Publication();

publication.Author = user;

user.Topics.Add(???);
```

At ??? you can't add `publication` because it isn't a `Topic` instance. `user.Topics` must refer to another object than `publication` which means that those endpoints cannot belong to the same association.

**Edit**

If you want only one single association with only a single foreign key column in the database you must either move the `Author` property from `Publication` to `Topic` or let the collection in your `User` class refer to `Publication` instead of `Topic`:

```
public ICollection<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
```